# Can I provide the icon to use for an iPhone homescreen shortcut to my web application?

Tags: iphone, ios, web-applications, iphone-standalone-web-app

I have a web application that will be used on iPhones, and want to provide the icon to be shown when added as a homescreen shortcut.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this HTML code in the `<head>` section of your start page:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="my_icon.png" />
```